# JS switch, how to increase numbers?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to build a js with a switch function. I want get the `innerHTML` from `html` with a different id name. However, how to increase numbers in this situation? thanks.

js code:

```
 function(buildindex){
    var i = 1;
    i = i + 1;
    i++;
        switch (buildindex){
            case i:
            return document.getElementById("testi").innerHTML;
        }
    }
```

html code:

```
<div id="test1">test1</div>
<div id="test2">test2</div>
<div id="test3">test3</div>
<div id="test4">test4</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? You are adding 1 to `i` twice, because `i = i + 1` is the same as `i++`. What exactly is your goal please?

Comment: Also, what is the point of the switch if there is only one case?  Why wouldn't you just call return document.getElementById("test" + i).innerHTML;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(buildindex){
     return document.getElementById('test' + buildindex).innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function(i) {
    return document.getElementById('test' + i).innerHTML;
}
```